# Publish WMS service from my own image rendering library

Tags: python, wms

I have written a Python package whose main function takes a bounding box as input, reads the according data from a data source of mine and renders it into a `png` image which is returned to the caller. On top of this library, one could easily add an `http` API or a command line interface for external usage without Python.

Now, I would like to publish my images as a `WMS` service so that I can view my layer using any standard `WMS` client like `QGIS`. Of course it would be possible to implement a fully compliant `WMS` API on top of my library, however, [the specification is kind of extensive](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) and allows for a lot of mistakes to make.

Is there any tool or library available that would do the heavy lifting of the `WMS` API but still can serve my own images which would be created by calling out to my Python library (using pure Python, a command line interface, an HTTP API or whatever works)?

I am aware of the following solutions and do not consider them to be suitable:

- Use [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) (or MapServer or uDig or ...) to do the rendering and publish the data as `WMS`. The way that my images are created is out of the scope of what GeoServer's styling features are capable of. Maybe I could write my own plugin for it but this sounds kind of heavy.
- Pre-render all possible images, put them into some folder and let that folder be served by `GeoServer` or similar tools. However, my data is too dynamic to be proxied for a long time and would outdate pretty quick.

Comment: Did you consider [OGCServer](https://github.com/mapnik/OGCServer)?

Comment: There exists also this https://github.com/sci-wms/sci-wms

Comment: To my understanding, both of these projects require a folder of pre-rendered map tiles. Instead, I would rather like to create my image on the fly from the most recent data in my datastore.